# Launch GUI: facade vs main

Tags: java, user-interface, facade

It is better to launch the user interface from a method in the same class of the main, or from a different class called by the main? Here an example:

**From the main**

*Main.java*

```
package main_version;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                launchGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void launchGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main version");
        //other code
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(333, 333);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**From another class**

*Main.java*

```
package facade_version;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UserInterface.lauch();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

*UserInterface.java*

```
package facade_version;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class UserInterface {

    public static void lauch() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Facade version");
        //other code
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(333, 333);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it makes any difference ?

Comment: @Dici : Regarding functionality certainly not. But with the facade the main class depends only from UserInterface class (and not with the JFrame and eventually the other graphical components).
Or am I wrong? The reason for the question is this.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend having each GUI component in a different class, for reusability.

However it makes no big difference for small projects, if one only wants to test something, he can just skip creating multiple classes. It makes no difference for the compiler.

Comment: Everything seems to be static here so there is no component in either case

Comment: @Dici JFrame is a component

Comment: I mean, the OP does not define any component. Usually, a GUI class would extend `JFrame` and have some attributes, creating a new component, but in this case everything is static. The two snippets are equivalent in every aspect